# duplicate value on select2 tag on laravel blade template

Tags: php, jquery-select2, laravel-7

I found a bug when i try to displayed data on select2 tag. I got duplicate data and I want to know how to fixed it. Im using laravel 7 and here's my code

This is my controller code:

```
public function editLocation(Request $request,$id){
$mtFasilitas = DB::table('MT_Facility')->select('id','name')
                                        ->get();
$trFasilitas = DB::table('TR_Fasilitas')->select('idMtFasilitas')
                                         ->where('idDetailLokasi',$id)
                                         ->get();
return view('layout.back.content_kos.edit_kos',['mtFas' => $mtFasilitas, 'trFas' => $trFasilitas]);
```

}

This is my blade template :

```
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple form-control mb-4" name="fasilitas[]" multiple="multiple">
                @foreach ($mtFas as $key => $data)
                    @foreach ($trFas as $key2 => $data2)
                        <option value="{{$data->id}}"{{$data2->idMtFasilitas == $data->id ? 'selected="selected"' : ''}}> {{ $data->name}}</option> 
                    @endforeach
                @endforeach
 </select>
```

And this is the result :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQuvI.png)

Anyone can help me ?
Thank you

Comment: ok sir @AndySong, i will modified. wait a second.

Comment: done sir, you can reload this page again @AndySong

Comment: ok sir @AndySong,
this is sample data for $mtFasilitas = [{"id":4,"name":"a"},{"id":5,"name":"b"},{"id":6,"name":"c"}]
this is data for $trFasilitas = [{"idMtFasilitas":4},{"idMtFasilitas":5}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$trFasilitas = DB::table('TR_Fasilitas')->select('idMtFasilitas')
                                         ->where('idDetailLokasi',$id)
                                         ->get()
                                         ->pluck('idMtFasilitas')
                                         ->all();
```

```php
        <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="fasilitas[]" multiple="multiple">
            @foreach ($mtFas as $data)
            <option value="{{ $data->id }}" {{in_array($data->id, $trFas) ? 'selected="selected"' : '' : ''}}>
                {{ $data->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
```

I think this should do.

Comment: still error sir. the error said : in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given

Answer (score 0):

This is the result of your updated answer sir @Andy Song
[image]

Comment: @Andy Song,
The value in option tag disapear and value selected didnt show

Comment: I just saw your message, sorry I will update my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

As per your data

$mtFasilitas = [{"id":4,"name":"a"},{"id":5,"name":"b"},{"id":6,"name":"c"}]

$trFasilitas = [{"idMtFasilitas":4},{"idMtFasilitas":5}]

Your inner loop running twice for each single value of outer loop, thats why data printed twice.